# Keep getting strange words in Google Keyboard's dictionary

Tags: gboard, dictionary

I keep getting strange words getting predicted by Google Keyboard's dictionary. I know I've never used them and doubt they would've come with the keyboard. One example is "Lync". I think some are names like "Bahar". Also slang words that I don't use like "kiddo" and abbreviations like "MSI and "SV". Also just the prediction seems strange, like I tried typing "something" and it came up with "softcover", which is a word I rarely use. How do I make it stick to more common words? I've tried resetting the custom dictionary but it didn't help.

Comment: Gboard suggests words based on some factors, including selected languages, and contact info (if you enable it). Are those words possibly related to the contacts in the device?

Comment: @AndrewT. there are some very bizarre words and names

Answer (score 0):

The Mysterious Japanese Dictionary

I can only think of one thing right off the top of my head. Gboard is reading and automatically importing a ASCII text encoded zip file from somewhere. Most likely  in the emulated/0/ path and everything within aka all recursive subdirectories and all content of said subdirectories. It could be an app that is using a zip file to run its code somehow or storing don't sort of data in a zip format that the app utilizes. It could be a bad extension somewhere, For example a folder or a file that contains ASCII text somewhere within and the extension of that folder\file somehow got changed into .zip...The possibilities are quite numerous now that I really think about it. The one concern I have about all this is the frequency and verbosity(intensity) that Google spies on everybody content... Personal or otherwise.

The reason I am interested in this topic(and I realize that this "answer" does not solve the issue at hand) is because this has and still is happening to my Gboard dictionary, Though I don't get random words that make no sense or don't go with what I am typing. So I tend to ignore the glitch/bug.
In fact Gboard somehow (without my knowledge/permission) located a .zip file, said hey this looks like a Japanese dictionary, processed to import the file, create an actual Japanese dictionary, and finally somehow created all new shortcuts for every single word. I've literally just sat here and scrolled down this mysteriously looking Japanese dictionary and still did not get to the bottom. There are thousands and thousands of "words" in the Japanese dictionary. So yeah, I think I will give it another go and try to track down the source of this mysterious Japanese dictionary that Gboard wants me to have so badly. (I tried to uninstall the app and reinstall it and it still searched through ALL folders and files to once again locate and import the Japanese dictionary that is completely unreadable, only to confirm my suspiciousness  and make me free like I was not going crazy for a second.

[image: screenshot of The Mysterious Japanese Dictionary]
[image: screenshot of shortcut (every single word has a shortcut)]
[image: screenshot: average size of the words in The Mysterious Japanese Dictionary]